# COUNT MySQL Parsing " unexpected '$result' (T_VARIABLE)"

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, count

I'm worknig on a basic website which provides suggestions for holiday countries.
First you like some countries and then it will "calculate" which countries are most suitably for you.
Problem is, at first I forgot that at first people were able to Like a country more than once. To prevent that I have come up with this code:

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost"; 
$db_username = "root";
$db_pass = ""; 
$db_name = "project"; 


$con = mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass","$db_name") or die ("could not connect to mysql");

$countryID = $_GET["country"];

$user = $_GET["user"];

$query = "SELECT COUNT(userID) AS identicalLikes FROM likes WHERE userID=".$user." AND countryID=".$countryID.";" // Counts how many times this country is already liked by this user

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$identicalLikes = $row['identicalLikes'];
?>
```

Then I check wether this number is zero, so I know whether I should add this to my database, or not (because it's already there).

I've done some research already, and I know what parsing is. But because I don't know whether the problem is in my query or in the parsing.

Does somebody know what I did wrong or have a better suggestion?
Making a boolean database is not an option since it's contents will grow very hard when more users join the site.

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **Avoid** using string interpolation to accomplish this as you have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this example.

Comment: Thanks! But what you haven't seen is that I used drop down menu's to choose. There isn't any field where you can enter strings. Don't know if that's 100% safe?

Comment: **Any** user data has to be presumed to be unsafe. That your HTML form has a drop-down means nothing because that could be changed. Even if this application isn't exposed to hostile users today, it might be in the future, and developing habits like this leads to nothing but horrible trouble in the future. The [Sony Hack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_Network_outage) was caused by mistakes like this, a simple mistake, so be disciplined about never making them in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a `;` at the end of your $sql definition:

```
$query = "SELECT [...snip...] countryID=".$countryID.";"; // Counts [..snip...]
                                                        ^---here
```

The quoted semicolon (`";"`) is part of the SQL statement, and is NOT terminating this line for PHP.

As well, you're vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) and haven't quoted your inserted values (assuming they're strings), so even after you fix this PHP syntax error, your SQL is still going to be fundamentally broken.